# WebApi Swagger (Swashbuckle) - can't access Swagger UI when connecting through proxy

Tags: c#, swagger, asp.net-web-api2, swashbuckle

I have a swagger (Swashbuckle) enabled on one of my API controllers.

Server sits on http://192.168.7.119:1001 and Swagger UI is accessed through http://192.168.7.119:1001/swagger.

When connecting locally, everything is fine and I can access Swagger UI on port 1001 as expected.
But when trying connect throug proxy on port 1000 (which redirects 1000 to 1001), I get a well known error:

"Can't read from server. It may not have the appropriate access-control-origin settings".

I have read this:

[Unable to access swagger despite cors enabled Asp.NET WebAPI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57573091/unable-to-access-swagger-despite-cors-enabled-asp-net-webapi/57693168#57693168)

and tried to set the RootUrl manually in Startup file, within Swagger like this:

```
.EnableSwagger(c => 
         {
             c.RootUrl(req => @"http://192.168.7.119:1001";
             ...
         });
```

CORS settings are set as:

```
appBuilder.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);
```

Any hints what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Can you post also the proxy configuration? The error might be on the proxy side.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Putting together this two pages from github repos of Swashbuckle the easy way to do what you're asking is:

- [From Github](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle/issues/1251#issuecomment-408439252) Make sure that your proxy is sending the X-Forwarded-* headers (Apache does it out of the box while Nginx doesn't seems so. You have to do some changes on the [nginx conf](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/likeapache/).
- [From Github](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle/issues/705#issuecomment-487083256). Create this HttpRequestMessageExtensions static class with the **ComputeHostAsSeenByOriginalClient** method and then

```cs
.EnableSwagger(c => 
         {
               c.RootUrl(req => req.ComputeHostAsSeenByOriginalClient());
             ...
         });
```